# PhpStorm IDE - Hold Cmd+Q to Quit

Tags: user-interface, phpstorm

Google Chrome has a useful feature to prevent you accidentally quitting. If you click <kbd>CMD</kbd>/<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Q</kbd>, you're able to hold <kbd>Q</kbd> to actually quit.

As PHPStorm takes a while to close (and you're probably deep in coding) and reopen is there a way to configure that keyboard shortcut?

Comment: There's a confirmation dialog "Do you really want to quit?" which [you can configure to] come[s] up… won't that help?

Answer (score 2):

It's not possible to set a hold to action on keyb. shortcut in PhpStorm, but there's an option to set "double press" of the keyb. shortcut to execute the action.

Open the File -> Settings -> Keymap, find the action you want to put the shortcut on, click Edit shortcuts -> Keyboard shortcuts and in the dialog check "Second stroke" option and put the same key combination.

[image]